# Connecting Android app running on Genymotion to Amazon RDS

Tags: android, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, genymotion

I am developing an Android application. I have to connect to Amazon RDS database. I already have created a database there. For experimenting, I have also duplicated the database on localhost. I believe that if I am able to connect to my localhost db then i will be able to connect to RDS later by just changing the connection URL. 
I am using good old JDBC connector. But I am unable to connect. Is it because I am using Genymotion to run my app?

```
private static final String TAG = "AddTaskActivity";
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.0.3.15:8080/dbname";
private static final String user = "root";
private static final String pass = "";


Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        System.out.println("Database connection successful");
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        int results = stmt.executeUpdate("***INSERT QUERY***");
        if (results == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Task added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is what I am using to connect. I am getting the driver but there seems to be a problem with the IP of localhost. I tried many IPs. 
Am I on right track?

Comment: The code as shown won't even compile, and please post any error message or exception stacktraces you get.